# No callback (onActivityResult) from startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I'm trying to include functionality in an app for taking photos. The camera activity comes up, I can take a photo and tap the checkmark for using the photo just taken, but the app never receives it because onActivityResult is never called.

Here is the code that activates the camera activity:

```
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
```

REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE is set to 1.

The onActivityResult method that is never called looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   ...
}
```

The app has only one activity, the main activity.
I have tried different settings in the manifest, with no luck.

Comment: By the way, I have also tried bringing up the activity for selecting a photo from gallery, with the same result: I can select a photo, but no callback.

Comment: Have you put a log in your onActivityResult?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both a Log.d and breakpoint to be sure whether the method is ever reached, and it never is.

Comment: Are you requested permission at runtime? (android >=6.0)

Comment: There are no questions about permissions at runtime. The app is running on Android 6.0.

Comment: Ok, you call your startActivityForResult from the Activity? If you call it from somewhere else it should be getActivity().startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

Comment: Are you calling this from inside a fragment maybe?

Comment: I call startActivityForResult from within public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 in a method there triggered by a setOnClickListener on a Button.

Comment: So debugging the application the debugger does not reach any line in the `onActivityResult()`? @RichardG.Nielsen

Comment: Correct. onActivityResult has never never called/reached/executed. Hasn't happened. Like, ever... ;)

Comment: @RichardG.Nielsen can you try changing `REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE` to some random higher number?

Answer (score 0):

As noted [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics) you have to add this in the manifest.

Once this is added:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                  android:required="true" />
```

After you took the photo and accept it, the callback is called

Comment: @RichardG.Nielsen than there's something else wrong in your code. I copy-paster your code in a new project, new activity and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false"/>


    private Uri mCapturedImageURI;

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, System.currentTimeMillis() + "PRESCRIPTION");
                        mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                        Intent intentPicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        intentPicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
                        startActivityForResult(intentPicture, 1);

     public String getCameraPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
            try {
                String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "";
            }
        }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
                case 1:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (mCapturedImageURI != null) {
                        realImagePath = getCameraPathFromURI(mCapturedImageURI);

                    }
                }
                break;
    }
```

Comment: I tried you code, but it failed with java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=19464, uid=10076 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
So I guess I need to add a permission in the manifest for this.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>